Add prefix to some java spring boot controllers
Is there a way to add a prefix to a group od controllers leaving the rest of the controllers out of this prefix
example:
@Slf4j
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/families")
@RolesGuard(role = {Roles.Manager, Roles.Employee})
public class MyController {
    ...
}

I already added the global prefix for the whole app using context-path but I want a custom prefix for this controller and the other controllers of same package without affecting the rest of the controllers without adding @RequestMapping(value = "/prefix/families") for example for every controller knowing that my controllers are grouped according to their functionality into several package (products, suppliers, ...)

I solved this by a solution as simple as a configuration class.

Step 1: Creat Configuration class:

package com.example.configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class PrefixConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        
    }
}


Step 2: Add path prefix using the configurer as follows:

    configurer.addPathPrefix(
                "/products", handler -> handler
                        .getPackage()
                        .getName()
                        .startsWith("com.example.products")
        );

Full code will be:
package com.example.configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class PrefixConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addPathPrefix(
                "/products", handler -> handler
                        .getPackage()
                        .getName()
                        .startsWith("com.example.products")
        );
    }
}

This will prefix all controllers in the package com.example.products with the prefix /products so the previous route /families will now be accessed as /products/families of course we can't forget the global prefix that need to be added to all endpoints.
